# Error: android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am unable to resolve this error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

[Gradle Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6agL.png)

Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.3

Below is the code of build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.app.test'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

/* IMPORTANT :
 * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // google library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    // library for api
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    // ripple effect library
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

Add this line of code below gradle.build(app)  section i hope it will work.

Comment: No its not working, still giving same error